# Understanding a Excel sumproduct formula involving exponent

Tags: excel-2007

I am trying to understand what this Excel Sumproduct formula is doing. 
I read on `SUMPRODUCT` function, but unable to catch the role played by the exponent, minus symbol and the sequence of actions, particularly the exponent being applicable to (C3:C4-B10) as a whole.

```
SUMPRODUCT((C3:C4-B10)^2,D3:D4)
```

The function produces a valid result. It is used in the context of standard deviation.

Can anyone mention the sequence of actions taken by the formula ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-writing the expression:

```
=(C3-B10)^2*D3+(C4-B10)^2*D4
```

So if **A1** contains the original formula and **A2** contains the re-written formula:

[image]